# Could `qsort()` grantee the sorted array in ascending order?

Tags: c, sorting

As per the documentation(https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=c/algorithm/qsort), which says:

> Sorts the given array pointed to by ptr in ascending order. The array
>   contains count elements of size bytes. Function pointed to by comp is
>   used for object comparison.

But,i could not agree.I think wethear the sorted array is in ascending order or not depends on the implementation of `int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)`.

**To the contrary**, as per documentation(cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/?kw=qsort), which says"Sorts the num elements of the array pointed to by base, each element size bytes long, using the compar function to determine the order.". They have opposite statement.Which one is right?

Comment: The documentation defines what `comp` needs to do. So if you pass in a non-conforming `comp` then it's an incorrect usage of `qsort` and hence the bug is in your code and not `qsort` nor the documentation.

Comment: You are right. The callback function tells `qsort` how to sort. For example suppose you are sorting an array of `struct` with two integer members. `qsort` will have *no idea* which member is being used to sort, or what the sequence is supposed to be. It might even be sorted by the product of its members. Another example is that they are coordinates on a plane, and are being sorted by distance from an external point. It would be *impossible* for `qsort` to make a decision.

Comment: Yes, the final order depends on the ordering provided by the comparison function. The wording on that page could be better.

Comment: @kaylum To the contrary, as per documentation(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/?kw=qsort), which says"Sorts the num elements of the array pointed to by base, each element size bytes long, using the compar function to determine the order.". They have opposite statement.Which one is right?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Which page? The page forementioned in my comment?

Comment: The doc in your original link says: "comparison function which returns ​a negative integer value if the first argument is less than the second,
a positive integer value if the first argument is greater than the second and zero if the arguments are equal.". So if that is conformed to then the sort is ascending.

Comment: The cppreference page agrees with the C language standard. In my copy, section [7.22.5.2] says "The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison function pointed to by compar, which is called with two arguments that point to the objects being compared." I wouldn't get too hung up on that web page. We all know the comparison function determines the ordering...

Comment: @sunshilong369 "*Ascending*" means that each element in the sorted array is less than or equal to the next. But `qsort` has no notion of "*less than*" other than the one you define in the provided `comp` function.

Comment: @dxiv  So, what's your conclusion?Could `qsort()` grantee the sorted array in ascending order?Which documentaion do you agree with?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Sorry, not sure where your confusion lies. The *purpose* of qsort is to sort an array in ascending order, and the very notion of "ascending order" is whatever your `comp` function provides.

Comment: @P.P  Does anybody have the permission to modify the page on cppreference.com?

Answer (score 2):

In official c18 standard ([link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)) qsort descriptions is:

> Description The qsort function sorts an array of nmemb objects, the
>   initial element of which is pointed to bybase. The size of each object
>   is specified bysize.
>
> The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to
>   a comparison function pointed to by compar, which is called with two
>   arguments that point to the objects being compared. The function shall
>   return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the
>   first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to,
>   or greater than the second.
>
> If two elements compare as equal, their order in the resulting sorted
>   array is unspecified.

Keep in mind [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) site is not the C standard. It purpose is described in the FAQ section: [FAQ](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:FAQ)

Comment: @coder Where do get the information aforementioned?Could you post the related url?

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification.But, your documetation forementioned is for C98, not C18.

Comment: @sunshilong369 see also here https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/issues/3189 same link provided